# Binding complex properties of a child class with a polymorphic model binder in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-binding

Recently I've been playing around with a [custom polymorphic modelbinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#polymorphic-model-binding), little more than what's in the docs, and I've come across a scenario I'm not sure how to handle.

I've implemented the model binder just like in the documentation, for a hierarchy similar to this:

```cs
public interface Step {}

public class StepWithSimpleProperty : Step
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class StepWithComplexProperty : Step
{
    public List<Complex> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that when binding the class with a Complex property, it doesn't seem to also bind the list of `Complex` instances.

Now, trying to go a little more into detail about my specific case, my Razor Page has a table somewhat like this:

```html
@model Project.Pages.StepWithComplexProperty

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Prop1</th>
        <th>Prop2</th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="MyList[@i].ID"/>
            <td>
                <input type="text" asp-for="MyList[@i].Prop1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" asp-for="MyList[@i].Prop2"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is the actual razor page:

```html
@page
@model Project.Pages.WizardViewModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    var currentStep = Model.Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex];
    var viewName = currentStep.ToString().Substring(currentStep.ToString().LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
}

<h3>Step @(Model.CurrentStepIndex + 1) out of @Model.Steps.Count</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Hidden("StepType", Model.Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex].GetType())
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CurrentStepIndex, Model.CurrentStepIndex)
    @Html.Partial("" + viewName + "", currentStep);

    if (Model.CurrentStepIndex > 0)
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Previous" name="prev" asp-page-handler="Previous" class="btn btn-secondary" />
    }

    if (Model.CurrentStepIndex < (Model.Steps.Count - 1))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" asp-page-handler="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
    else
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Finish" name="finish" asp-page-handler="Finish" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
}
```

And the view model for the razor page:

```cs
public class WizardViewModel : PageModel
{
    [BindRequired]
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public int CurrentStepIndex { get; set; }

    public IList<Step> Steps { get; set; }
    
    // Constructor and methods, below, but not relevant for the problem ...
}
```

In that `PageModel` it has the property of type `List<Step>`, which is each element representing a step of a wizard, a big form. Each of the classes that implement `Step` are simply *View Models*. And, like mentioned, moving back and forth through the wizard works fine... except for the step which as a list of complex objects, which the model binder seems to ignore. In case it helps, I'll post the code of the model binder below:

---

*WizardModelBinder.cs*

```cs
public class WizardModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private Dictionary < Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder) > binders;

    public WizardModelBinder(Dictionary < Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder) > binders)
    {
        this.binders = binders;
    }

    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("StepType").FirstValue;
        var modelType = Type.GetType(modelTypeValue, true);

        IModelBinder modelBinder;
        ModelMetadata modelMetadata;
        if (modelTypeValue.Contains("Step"))
        {
            (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[modelType];
        }
        else
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
            return;
        }

        var newBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
            bindingContext.ActionContext,
            bindingContext.ValueProvider,
            modelMetadata,
            bindingInfo : null,
            bindingContext.ModelName);

        await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(newBindingContext);
        bindingContext.Result = newBindingContext.Result;

        if (newBindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
        {
            // Setting the ValidationState ensures properties on derived types are correctly 
            bindingContext.ValidationState[newBindingContext.Result] = new ValidationStateEntry
            {
                Metadata = modelMetadata,
            };
        }
    }
}

public class WizardModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(Step))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var subclasses = new []
        {
            typeof(StepWithSimpleProperty),
            typeof(StepWithComplexProperty),
        };

        var binders = new Dictionary < Type,
            (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder) > ();

        foreach (var type in subclasses)
        {
            var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);
            binders[type] = (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
        }

        return new WizardModelBinder(binders);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear about the issue.Where  did you use `WizardModelBinder` ? And how did you use `Step` interface ? Could you share more details about the PageModel and the corresponding Razor Pages, or a complete demo  link that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @XueliChen I just added more details. That should give enough context. Basically I think it's the default model binder which is generated for `StepWithComplexProperty` not filling in the complex property, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in your BindModelAsync method? Is it pulling the correct type from the dictionary?

Comment: Also when you say is "not working".... what do you mean? What is it supposed to be doing and that its not?  Are you getting errors? What exactly is the problem?  It is not clear to me what the problem is.  And I fail to see why you need a custom binder at all.

Comment: Old question I know, but I'm working on the same problem. In case it helps steer others. The issue seems to be in rendering the tags in the partial view with the correct name attribute; asp-for="MyList[@i].Prop1", should probably be asp-for="Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex].MyList[@i].Prop1" to bind correctly in the pagemodel.